# Apache beam wildcard recursive search for files

Tags: java, scala, apache-beam, spotify-scio

I am using Spotify's Scio library for writing apache beam pipelines in scala. I want to search for files under a directory in a recursive way on a filesystem which can be hdfs, alluxio or GCS. Like *.jar should find all the files under the provided directory and sub-directories.

Apache beam sdk provided `org.apache.beam.sdk.io.FileIO` class for such purpose where I can find files on one directory level using `pipeline.apply(FileIO.match().filepattern(filesPattern))`.

How can I make it recursive to search for all files matching the provided pattern?

Currently, I am trying another approach, where I am creating resourceId of the provided pattern and getting current directory of the provided pattern, then I am trying to resolve all sub-directories in the current directory using `resourceId.resolve()` method. But it is throwing an exception for it.

```
    val currentDir = FileSystems.matchNewResource(filesPattern, false).getCurrentDirectory
    val childDir = currentDir.resolve("{@literal *}", StandardResolveOptions.RESOLVE_DIRECTORY)
```

For `currentDir.resolve` I am getting following exception:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
 The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error.
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:546)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:421)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:427)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:813)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.runProgram(CliFrontend.java:287)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:213)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1050)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$11(CliFrontend.java:1126)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1836)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.HadoopSecurityContext.runSecured(HadoopSecurityContext.java:41)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1126)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in path at index 0: {@literal *}/
        at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:852)
        at java.net.URI.resolve(URI.java:1036)
        at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.hdfs.HadoopResourceId.resolve(HadoopResourceId.java:46)
        at com.sparkcognition.foundation.ingest.jobs.copyjob.FileOperations$.findFiles(BinaryFilesSink.scala:110)
        at com.sparkcognition.foundation.ingest.jobs.copyjob.BinaryFilesSink$.main(BinaryFilesSink.scala:39)
        at com.sparkcognition.foundation.ingest.jobs.copyjob.BinaryFilesSink.main(BinaryFilesSink.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:529)
        ... 12 more
Caused by: java.net.URISyntaxException: Illegal character in path at index 0: {@literal *}/
        at java.net.URI$Parser.fail(URI.java:2848)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.checkChars(URI.java:3021)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parseHierarchical(URI.java:3105)
        at java.net.URI$Parser.parse(URI.java:3063)
        at java.net.URI.<init>(URI.java:588)
        at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:850)
        ... 22 more
```

Please suggest what should be the right way to search for files recursively using apache beam?

References:
https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.11.0/index.html?org/apache/beam/sdk/io/fs/ResourceId.html

Comment: Take into account that, at least for GCS, you can use the `**` wildcard to match recursively ([example](https://github.com/gxercavins/dataflow-samples/blob/master/timestamps-in-path/src/main/java/com/dataflow/samples/ChronologicalOrder.java#L51)). Otherwise, you can also try to get the list using each source's library (Java example for [GCS](https://gist.github.com/gxercavins/3187e37c9799bdaee58cf1ceae4e808c)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have some code copied from some [faulty javadoc](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.11.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/fs/ResourceId.html#resolve-java.lang.String-org.apache.beam.sdk.io.fs.ResolveOptions-).  Some old versions of the example code were published with errors around the asterisks.

To find all files inside currentDir:

```scala
val childDir = currentDir.resolve("**", StandardResolveOptions.RESOLVE_FILES)
```